# Images getting refreshed on scrolling listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using a listview that have 3 fields, 1 imageview and 2 textview. I am parsing the json data for listview. When I scroll the listview, images in the imageview changes and then when i scroll back to the top, it again changes. I am displaying image from the URLs.

Below is some of the code:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap> dataToList(List<CatalogTopCategory> detailsList) {
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    for (CatalogTopCategory catalogTopCategory : detailsList) {
        HashMap temp = new HashMap();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, catalogTopCategory.getCategoryName());
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, catalogTopCategory.getCategoryDesc());
        temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, catalogTopCategory.getCategoryBannner());
        temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, catalogTopCategory.getCategoryThumbnail());
        temp.put(FORTH_COLUMN, catalogTopCategory.getCategoryId());
        list.add(temp);
    }
    return list;
}



final ArrayList<HashMap> hashMaps = dataToList(storeCatList);
        catalogTopAdapter = new CatalogTopAdapter(StoreLanding.this,
                hashMaps, getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(catalogTopAdapter);
```

Below is the adapter class code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_listview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
                holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SecondText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/FeedSpeedFonts.otf"); 
            holder.txtFirst.setTypeface(type);
            holder.txtSecond.setTypeface(type);
            HashMap map = list.get(position);
            new LoadImage(holder.imageView).execute(String.valueOf(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN)));
            holder.txtFirst.setText((CharSequence) map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
            holder.txtSecond.setText((CharSequence) map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));                
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
}
```

Load Image:

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public LoadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.default_image);
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 100, 100,
                false));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post getView() of adpter class code.

Comment: `new LoadImage(holder.imageView).execute(String.valueOf(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN)));`   what is this..??

Comment: I think in each load its getting some image from server and reflecting in imageview as per  the position

Comment: Are you sure only images are changing or text on textview also?

Comment: @Raghavendra It will only reflect the imageview i think as it is filling through threads

Comment: Only images are getting changed not the texts in textview.

Comment: @Sakshi You can use lazyloader ..

Comment: Is that really your adapter, I ask this because I usually do not use getView but onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder. Like this it seems you are creating a new holder for every getView and holder's purpose is to create it once and reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use picasso library to simplify your image downloading process. Picasso is open source and one of the widely used image downloader library in Android. You down load it form this [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

and just replace your image downloading with the following snippet in getView() method.

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder) // optional
    .error(R.drawable.ic_error_fallback)         // optional
    .into(imageView);
```

This may not be a solution for your problem but an alternative.

Comment: if it solved your problems then you show gratitude by mark the answer as accepted and up vote it.

Comment: @AnsalAli I am trying to replace image with another. When I didn't add placeholder (as you said its optional). it clears old image until new image is downloaded and placed. Can you tell me how handle that?

Comment: you can replace image in the drawable just before you need to change the image with something says downloading image or loading image. so that until the image loads the, your imageView says itself says the image is downloading and user can understand that easily.

Answer (score 2):

This `new LoadImage(holder.imageView).execute(String.valueOf(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN)));` cause problem with refreshing images. You start asynctask evry time when view is refreshed. When your view will be reused your asynck task show bad image on position, so your asynctask starts again and display good image. You can not set images in that way. Android community use

- Picasso
- Universal Image Loader
- Volley Image Loader
- Glide

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Volley** library which has **NetworkImageView** .Feel free to refer this link [Volley Networkimageview example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)